# Android - Looping worker for 1 minute

Tags: java, android, loops, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I've been searching for lots of articles about how to run a specific functions and methods within a certain time, for example, 5 minutes but I couldn't find at least a similar case with mine. Now, in my use case, I would like to run a worker over and over in 1 minute. I planned this use case for handling network connection, so the apps will try to connect to the server within that 1 minute and if it's failed then the user can press the retry button. How am I supposed to do to achieve what I want?

Here's my doWork :

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.e("MyWork", "Starting Worker");
        for (long stop = System.nanoTime()+ TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1); stop>System.nanoTime();) {
            Log.e("MyWork", "Running Worker in 1 Minute");
        }
//        Been using below's code but still didn't work
//        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//        while ((System.nanoTime()-startTime)< 5*60){
//            Log.e("MyWork", "Running Worker in 1 Minute");
//        }
        Log.e("MyWork", "Done Running Worker in 1 Minute");
        return Result.retry();
    }
```

What I want to achieve is :

1. I want to repeat the execution of doWork() function within 1 minute
2. The user can not do retry if the connection is not reached yet within 1 minute
3. If the apps still can not reach the connection within 1 minute, then the user can press the retry button
4. Here's the output I wish I could achieve :

   E/MyWork: Starting Worker

   E/MyWork: Running Worker in 1 Minute with seconds - 1

   E/MyWork: Running Worker in 1 Minute with seconds - 2

   E/MyWork: Running Worker in 1 Minute with seconds - 3

   E/MyWork: Running Worker in 1 Minute with seconds - 4

   E/MyWork: Running Worker in 1 Minute with seconds - ...

   E/MyWork: Running Worker in 1 Minute with seconds - 60

   E/MyWork: Done Running Worker in 1 Minute

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a CountDownTimer like here:

```
       new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            doWork()
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("MyWork", "Done running worker in 1 minute");

        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: We can not call doWork() in that way, it's an override from the Worker library. and also, I want to create that looping inside doWork() in the Worker class.